# Chrome treating CSS quite particularly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this CSS layout which works fine in both Firefox/Opera and even in Safari, but in Chrome behaves slightly differently.

I have the usual:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body { height: 100%; }

div#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 1000px;      /* giving the page a fixed width */
    margin: 0 auto;     /* centering the page */
    position: relative; /* making the footer stop when it meets the content */
}
```

Now, everything works fine except when I refresh the page in Chrome. In all the other browsers, when I refresh the page the content adapts itself and (if the height of the page isn't less than the minimum height of the content) I don't have to scroll down to see the whole page. In Chrome, when I refresh the page becomes bigger than the screen and I have to scroll down to see it all. Note that the content shouldn't be the problem because it does not exceed the height of the main section.

The HTML layout is basically:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">

        <header>stuff...</header>

        <section id="page_content">stuff...</section>

        <footer>stuff...</footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

And, if it can help, the CSS of the main content is:

```
section#page_content {
    height: 100%;       /* pay attention: height is actually handled */
    min-height: 400px;  /* by the jQuery code, which resizes it dynamically */
    max-height: 1000px;
    width: 802px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And also this JS function is called every time the page is resized **and** when the page loads:

```
function resizeMainSection() {
    var finalHeight = $(window).height()
        - $('footer#page_footer').outerHeight(true)
        - $('header#page_header').outerHeight(true) // a simple div to stop the footer from going over the content when resizing
        - $('div#footer_stopper').outerHeight(true);
    var mainSection = $('section#page_content');

    if (finalHeight < mainSection.css('min-height')
        || finalHeight > mainSection.css('max-height')) return;
    $(mainSection).height(finalHeight);
}
```

What are the possible causes?

#### Edit

I noted that only when I **refresh** the page (through <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or through the refresh button) I get this issue. If I re-insert the same URL into the browser and I click <kbd>Enter</kbd> the layout is styled correctly. So maybe it's a cache problem as someone suggested in the comments.

Comment: If it is only chrome issue then it might be related to clearing cache. But I think your issue is different here.

Comment: 1) Are there any errors in the Chrome developer tools (F12) console tab? 2) I'm not familiar with the exact syntax you used around the 'return' bit of your jQuery resizing/load function (which isn't to say it isn't valid!). Have you tried restating that bit in another way to see if it's causing problems?

Comment: @smclark89 `return` means get out of the function **now**. I use it in order to avoid resizing when the height would be too big/small.
Anyway, Chrome signals no errors in the console.

Comment: @Mr_Green maybe it is a cache-related issue after all, see my edit for details

Comment: Inspect the element(s) and look at the CSS styles that are applied -- do they appear to be correct?

Comment: Ok well you got your answer. I suggest you to delete this post. as it doesn't have any issues with code or any other problem now. It's completely your wish. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better script would be to change the end from

```
if (finalHeight < mainSection.css('min-height')
    || finalHeight > mainSection.css('max-height')) return;
$(mainSection).height(finalHeight);
```

to:

```
if (finalHeight < mainSection.css('min-height') 
    finalHeight = mainSection.css('min-height');
if (finalHeight > mainSection.css('max-height')
    finalHeight = mainSection.css('max-height');
$(mainSection).height(finalHeight);
```

That is the height is a value constrained by a min and a max values. If the calculated value is below the min, the apropiate action is to set it to the min, not to exit the script